# IIS URL Re-Direct to local host and port

Tags: apache, iis, virtualhost, proxypass

I'm in the process of breaking apart and migrating an apache internal webserver to an IIS web server.

I believe what the snippet of apache web config does below when testing is re-direct any requests coming in from "bobby" to http://localhost:8181/

bobby is a DNS entry on our domain which resolves to 192.168.8.50.

In short, if you place bobby/ into a web browser on our domain without the port specified the below will forward to local host with the correct port.

How can I replicate this in IIS?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.8.50:80>
    ServerName bobby

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off

    <Proxy *>
         Require all granted
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8181/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8181/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to redirect all the request from the "bobby" to "http://localhost:8181/"?

If this is your requirement , I suggest you could try to use IIS url rewrite module IIS reverse proxy to achieve your requirement.

You could install it from this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).

Then you could add below config settings in the bobby web.config file in system.webServer tag.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8181/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: If you feel my reply help you, please mark it as answer. This will make  other people who faces the same issue to find the answer more easily. Thank you.